# Constrain two rows to be different

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I need to add a constraint to a table that will force the values in each row to be different.
ex.

```
ID | Column1(int) | Column2(int)
```

---

```
1  |     5        |    5
```

---

I need to stop this from being allowed.
Any Ideas on how I can Constrain Column 2 from being the same as Column 1?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do they need to be different? (the need for this restriction _could_ stem from a violation of 1NF)

Comment: In this case it is due to Column 1 being an ID column and Column 2 being a parentID column.  So this is to prevent the row from becoming it's own parent.

Comment: Ah, the `lenght=1` loop. Had not thought about that one. But you might also want to prevent `length > 1` loops, and your constraint would not prevent that general case. (BTW: `parent=self` is often used as sentinel value, eg for orphans. Easy to check, and allows NOT NULL to be enforced, too)

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers which can validate INSERT or UPDATE before its execution. If column values equals, it can throw an exception/error.

However, it might be better to enforce this constraint on application side (but this depends ...)

Comment: Good ideas, however I'm trying to troubleshoot a very elusive bug in the application that happens rarely, and I want to force the application to throw an exception.  Also I'm working with Amazon RDS, so I can't really use triggers.  But thanks for the ideas!